# Problems printing from buf while reading pipe

Tags: c, pipe, fifo

I am trying to create communication between server and client in C using **mkfifo**.

In the image below you have the code i wrote to read from the pipe called **fifo** and to write on terminal. I use the system call write to write in the console from the buf and it's all good, but that printf should print the same thing as the write call.

```
int fifo_fd = open("fifo", O_WRONLY);

int pid = getpid();

char buff_pid[sizeof(pid) + 3];

sprintf(buff_pid, "%d:", pid);

char buf[1024];
int bytes_read;

while ((bytes_read = read(0,buf, 1024)) > 0 ){

    write(fifo_fd,buff_pid, sizeof(buff_pid));
    
    write(fifo_fd,buf, bytes_read);
}
```

However, this is what is going on. In the left we have the server, and in the right we have the client. Client send a message to the server, and then the server read it and write it on terminal with client's pid.

[image]

And this is what is happening, **printf** should print the pid and the message from de buf, but this is not happening and i don't know why.

I add my client's code. I use two buffers, one to send the pid and other one to send message, because i had problems using only one buffer

Comment: Are you sure there are no embedded NULs (zero bytes) in the data? `write` writes a fixed number of raw bytes (NULs aren't special), but the `%s` code for `printf` is going to stop at NULs (because that's where C-strings end; the rest of it would be ignored). Your terminal might also erase data if there are `\r` or `\b` characters embedded in there.

Comment: So the client's working and the server's working, but when you interconnect them, it fails? Sounds like a problem with how your opening it if you can print to `/dev/stdout` without any trouble, but not to a fifo. Maybe edit your post, including the client's code as well?

Comment: Keep in mind that `printf` is line buffered -- stdout isn't flushed until you write a `\n`. I think that it's more likely that you have some non printible characters that are causing issues, but in general, buffering issues can be very purplexing, so you should avoid the problem by adding the newline.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: @stackoverflowuser already added my client's code

Comment: @BartonChittenden maybe the issue is related with `\n`, but how can i fix it?

Comment: @ShadowRanger i think i don't have `\r`or `\b`characters embedded in terminal

Comment: `char buff_pid[sizeof(pid) + 3];` This makes no sense at all and is likely to result in a a buffer overrun.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. so, how should i do it to write the pid with ":" to separate from de message?

Comment: Number of characters needed to print a number is not the same as its `sizeof`. For most Unix systems, 10 characters should be enough to print pid_t, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16883/

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it, in plain old and dirty C, tested in Debian Buster, Eclipse CDT. You'll need to replace `/home/myhomedir/myfifo` in the file name for the appropriated path on your filesystem. FIFO file previously created using `mkfifo /home/myhomedir/myfifo`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int fdRd = open("/home/myhomedir/myfifo", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fdRd < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    int fdWr = open("/home/myhomedir/myfifo", O_WRONLY);
    if (fdWr < 0) {
        close(fdRd);
        return -1;
    }

    char buf[64];

    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 5; cnt++) {
        sprintf(buf, "demo %i\n", cnt);
        write(fdWr, buf, strlen(buf));
        int len = read(fdRd, buf, sizeof(buf)-1);
        if (len > 0) {
            buf[len] = '\0';
            fwrite(buf, sizeof(buf[0]), strlen(buf), stdout);
        }
    }
    close(fdRd);
    close(fdWr);
    return 0;
}
```

It will printout:

> demo 0
> demo 1
> demo 2
> demo 3
> demo 4